# cakepdf dompdf notice undefined variable

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

am trying to generate pdf from view using cakepdf but its not working as expected.please bear with me its my first time using this plugin.

here is my set up

**controller action**

```
$this->pdfConfig = array(
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => $report['reg_no'],
            'permissions' => array(
                'print','screen_readers','copy_contents'
            )
        );
        $cakePdf = new CakePdf();  //create an instance of the cakePdf class
        $cakePdf->template('pdf_view','default');  //define view to use and optional layout

        $pdf = $cakePdf->output();
        $pdf = $cakePdf->write(APP . 'webroot' .DS .'files'. DS . 'report.pdf');
        //$this->set('tcpdf',$tcpdf);
        $this->set('report',$report);
        $this->render('/Pdf/pdf_view');
```

**my pdf_view.ctp has this code: its fairly long**

```
<style>
tr .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    width:100px;
}
tr .text {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```
<div>
<?php 
if($report['school']['logo'] == NULL){echo  $this->Html->image('/logo_small.png',array('width'=>'100px','height'=>'100px'));
    }else {
        echo $this->Html->image($report['school']['logo'],array('width'=>'100px','height'=>'100px'));
    }
?>
<p>
    <font size="5"><b><?php echo $report['school']['name']; ?></b></font><br />
    <b><?php echo $report['school']['motto']; ?></b><br />
    <b><?php echo $report['school']['address']; ?></b>
</p>
<p align="center"><b><font size="4">Report Card</font></b></p>

<div>
<table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Admission_no</td>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $report['reg_no']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Form</td>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $report['form']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Position</td>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $report['rank']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Name</td>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $report['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Stream</td>
        <td class="text"><?php if($report['stream'] == NULL){
            echo "<N/A>";
            }else {
                echo $report['stream'];
                } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Out Of</td>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $report['outof']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="clear:left"><hr />
<!--<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php /*foreach ($report['subjects'] as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['score']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['grade']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['points']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $totPoints += $value['points'];
            endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><?php echo $report['total']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $totPoints;*/ ?></td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>-->
</div>
<br /><hr /><br />
<p>
    <font size="4"><b>Class Teacher Remarks</b></font><br /><br />
    <font size="4"><b>Principal Remarks</b></font><br /><br />
    <font size="4"><b>Fees Balance</b></font><br />
    <font size="4"><b>Closing Date</b></font>
    <font size="4"><b>Opening Date</b></font>
</p>
```

**problems:**

1.the inline styles for the table are not applied.

2.the generated pdf is full of notices about undefined variable: report in the pdf_view.ctp(yet i used

```
$this->set('report',$report)
```

in my controller action)

3. my image is not displayed in the pdf even after setting this in dompdf_config.inc.php

   define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);

4.about the commented out tbody tag..if i uncomment it i get error

```
Error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute() 
File: /home/r2d2/web-php/sms/app/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/dompdf/include  /cellmap.cls.php 
Line: 400
```

**question:  why am i getting undefinde variable report,image not loading,styles not applying and #4 above**..

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve all my issues.may be of help to another first time plugin user:

1.realized you cannot pass variable for pdf rendering like you do for views.instead following other answers here on stackoverflow:this worked

```
$this->viewVars(array("report",$report));
```

2.images::solved by adding fullbase array options:

```
echo $this->Html->image($report['school']['logo'],array('width'=>'100px','height'=>'100px','fullBase'=>true));
```

3.removed the tbody tag.turned out from the documentation most of my css styles were not supported